# Disable all warnings from a specific module

Tags: python, warnings, suppress-warnings

I would like to disable all warnings coming from a specific module, such that

```py
import foo
import bar

foo.warning_method() # should not warn
bar.warning_method() # should warn
```

Is there a way to control this, or do I need to  set a filter for all specific warning types?

Answer (score 7):

Found the solution: The `module` argument:

```
import warnings

warnings.filterwarnings('ignore', module='foo')
```